# Flutter and Dark extensions not showing in Visual Studio Code

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I am trying to learn how to use Flutter and am using Visual Studio Code. When in Visual Studio Code and with a project selected, I try to: `run > run without debugging`. I am then supposed to see a list of my installed extensions to choose between - something like this:

[image]

but instead I see:

[image]

as if there are no extensions installed. However you can see:

[image]

that I do have Flutter and Dart extensions installed.

So I'm trying to figure out why my extensions are not showing. Any help gratefully received!

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

You need to open **main.dart** or any other **dart file**. Then do `run without debugging`.